# Why can't the elements of my array be parsed properly?

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, inputstream, printwriter

Java newbie here, I'm learning about InputStream class and did tried to implement a code I found on Cay S. Horstmann's Core Java Volume II, tenth edition. This code is supposed to show how Input/OutputStream classes are useful when reading bytes sequences by saving and reading data from an array into a file. It starts with a declaration of an array with given strings and int numbers, saving the elements of this array in a .dat file, reading the elements from the .dat file and displaying them in console.

But I get this in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '0' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:385)
    at chapter2.TextFileTest.readEmployee(TextFileTest.java:100)
    at chapter2.TextFileTest.readData(TextFileTest.java:76)  
    at chapter2.TextFileTest.main(TextFileTest.java:35)  
C:\Users\barcejo1\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets  \run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 21 seconds)
```

It seems like the problem lies when parsing respectively the int numbers of each row into variables that would be written in .dat file. I copied this code, and I don't get why it doesn't work.
I expect harsh answers, it's ok. I'm glad to be educated.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

/*** @version 1.14 2016-07-11
* @author Cay Horstmann
*/
public class TextFileTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
     Employee[] staff = new Employee[3];

     staff[0] = new Employee("Carl Cracker", 75000, 1987, 12, 15);
     staff[1] = new Employee("Harry Hacker", 50000, 1989, 10, 1);
     staff[2] = new Employee("Tony Tester", 40000, 1990, 3, 15);

     // save all employee records to the file employee.dat
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("employee.dat", "UTF-8"))
        {
        writeData(staff, out);
        }

     // retrieve all records into a new array
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("employee.dat"), "UTF-8"))
        {
        Employee[] newStaff = readData(in);

            // print the newly read employee records
            for (Employee e : newStaff)
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

     //Writes all employees in an array to a print writer

    private static void writeData(Employee[] employees, PrintWriter out) throws IOException
    {
       // write number of employees
       out.println(employees.length);

       for (Employee e : employees)
       writeEmployee(out, e);
    }

     /**
     * Reads an array of employees from a scanner
     * @param in the scanner
     * @return the array of employees
     */
    private static Employee[] readData(Scanner in)
    {
       // retrieve the array size
       int n = in.nextInt();
       in.nextLine(); // consume newline

       Employee[] employees = new Employee[n];
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
        employees[i] = readEmployee(in);
     }
       return employees;
    }

     /**
     * Writes employee data to a print writer
     * @param out the print writer
     */
    public static void writeEmployee(PrintWriter out, Employee e)
    {
       out.println(e.getName() + "|" + e.getSalary() + "|" + e.getHireDay());
    }

     /**
     * Reads employee data from a buffered reader
     * @param in the scanner
     */
    public static Employee readEmployee(Scanner in)
    {
       String line = in.nextLine();
       String[] tokens = line.split("\\|");
       String name = tokens[0];
       double salary = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
       LocalDate hireDate = LocalDate.parse(tokens[2]);
       int year = hireDate.getYear();
       int month = hireDate.getMonthValue();
       int day = hireDate.getDayOfMonth();
       return new Employee(name, salary, year, month, day);
    }
}
```

Comment: The stack trace shows that the error occurs in readEmployee, at line 100. Use your debugger and set a breakpoint at that line to inspect the values of the variables. Or simply add println() satements to know what they contain. That should tell you what is happening. Also read your .dat file with a text editor to check what it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are just writing day in file. 
Below is the fixed code:

```
 package com.example.demo;

import java.io.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

/***
 * @version 1.14 2016-07-11
 * @author Cay Horstmann
 */
public class TextFileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Employee[] staff = new Employee[3];

        staff[0] = new Employee("Carl Cracker", 75000, 1987, 12, 15);
        staff[1] = new Employee("Harry Hacker", 50000, 1989, 10, 1);
        staff[2] = new Employee("Tony Tester", 40000, 1990, 3, 15);

        // save all employee records to the file employee.dat
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("employee.dat", "UTF-8")) {
            writeData(staff, out);
        }

        // retrieve all records into a new array
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("employee.dat"), "UTF-8")) {
            Employee[] newStaff = readData(in);

            // print the newly read employee records
            for (Employee e : newStaff)
                System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    //Writes all employees in an array to a print writer

    private static void writeData(Employee[] employees, PrintWriter out) throws IOException {
        // write number of employees
        out.println(employees.length);

        for (Employee e : employees)
            writeEmployee(out, e);
    }

    /**
     * Reads an array of employees from a scanner
     * 
     * @param in the scanner
     * @return the array of employees
     */
    private static Employee[] readData(Scanner in) {
        // retrieve the array size
        int n = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine(); // consume newline

        Employee[] employees = new Employee[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            employees[i] = readEmployee(in);
        }
        return employees;
    }

    /**
     * Writes employee data to a print writer
     * 
     * @param out the print writer
     */
    public static void writeEmployee(PrintWriter out, Employee e) {
        //System.out.println(LocalDate.of(e.getYear(), e.getMonth(), e.getHireDay()).toString());
        out.println(e.getName() + "|" + e.getSalary() + "|" + LocalDate.of(e.getYear(), e.getMonth(), e.getHireDay()).toString());
    }

    /**
     * Reads employee data from a buffered reader
     * 
     * @param in the scanner
     */
    public static Employee readEmployee(Scanner in) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\|");
        String name = tokens[0];
        double salary = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
        LocalDate hireDate = LocalDate.parse(tokens[2]);
        int year = hireDate.getYear();
        int month = hireDate.getMonthValue();
        int day = hireDate.getDayOfMonth();
        return new Employee(name, salary, year, month, day);
    }
}
```